# Is a gold medalist at 2.96/4 GPA considered Summa cum laude or magna cum laude or none?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, gpa, india

Indian university(IIT BHU) CGPA of 7.4/10 but highest in the class, hence gold medalist. Can anyone please guide how the translation to US academic system will look like in terms of the label?

Note: No idea if this matters but my 5 year course had 1.5 years of absolute marking scheme and 3.5 years of relative grading.

Comment: This is up to your university. "Honors" can only be assigned by the university, not assumed. And, numeric GPA means different things in different systems. In the US, Summa Cum Laude might require 3.9/4, for example. Magna = 3.7, perhaps.

Comment: The Latin-named honors (e..g, _summa cum laude_) would be granted by graduating school. If your school doesn't have them, then you you would not get the honor.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to convert your grade like that. And why can't you just say "gold medalist" and "highest in class" where you need to, e.g. in your CV?

Comment: @GoodDeeds This is specifically for forms where they ask if you have graduated normally or with some distinction/cum laudes etc. If I choose graduated normally, there is no opportunity to show the meaning of my (low) GPA.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your university specifically confers an honor, you don't hold it.The three typical Latin honors have different meaning in different universities, if they have any meaning at all. And, 2.96/4.0 would not be considered very high if earned in a US university.

But that last bit means nothing as the systems are very different and grades are assigned very differently. I think it might be very difficult to impossible to achieve 9.something/10 in India, but don't have any experience. Getting 4.0/4.0 in the US is fairly common, actually and most folks bound for graduate study have something like 3.5 or better (but it varies and lots of other things "count").

If you apply for a graduate program in the US, the university is very likely to be able to do a fair translation of your India-earned grades into something that a US faculty member could evaluate. They have a lot of experience with it.

But, in general, don't claim honors that haven't be officially awarded by some organization that has the authority to do so.

---

At my old university, the breakout was 3.5/4.0 for Cum Laude, 3.7 for Magna, and 3.9 for Summa. My diploma shows Cum Laude, and putting it on the diploma would be typical if it is earned. I think those numbers are common, but I'm pretty sure they aren't universal.

---

Graduating "first" in your class has little actual meaning in the US other than something nice to tell your mom. It can be given meaning by a faculty member who writes a letter of recommendation, but there is no real official "honor". The Valedictorian at a US university might be awarded to the highest performing student overall, but that is across all majors (specialties). The valedictorian typically gives a short speech at the graduation ceremony. But even that is mostly just a "bragging point".

Comment: Thanks for explaining so well. My university had a low scoring methodology for first 3 semesters and they also changed the grading system for last 2 semesters (total soup!)
So even being top of the class I have a 'low' GPA. Most of the application forms just ask your GPA and then any additional honor - with the options never having a "top of class" field. I don't claim distinction or any of the cum-laude-s as you said it wouldn't be right to claim what isn't conferred.
To your point of translation of grades, is there any content on this for more info?